# Lost HDMI sound somehow

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 15.04, hdmi

A few days ago, everything with my HDMI was working fine - sound and video. Yesterday, PulseAudio Volume Control no longer detects HDMI output as an audio output - video still works fine. I don't think I changed any programs or files that would effect this, but running `alsamixer` now says `cannot open mixer: no such file or directory`. How do I make `alsamixer` and PulseAudio work again?

Screenshots:
Upgraded and uninstalled programs since it last worked:
[image: Software Center Changes]

PulseAudio Output Devices: (Should have digital option)
[image: PulseAudio]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you hit the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1457369.

It will be fixed in 3.19.0-20.20 which will be released the end of this week. If you can't wait, you can either downgrade your kernel or grab 3.19.0-20.20 from trusty-proposed (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed)